# Duplicate Routing in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to be able to pass this 2 routes in AngularJS :

```
.state('app.article', {
     url: '/:catName/:articleName',
     views: {
         'menuContent': {
             templateUrl: 'templates/article.html',
             controller: 'ArticleCtrl'
         }
     }
 })

 .state('app.category', {
     url: '/:catName/:subcatName',
     views: {
         'menuContent': {
             templateUrl: 'templates/category.html',
             controller: 'CategoryCtrl'
         }
     }
 })
```

The problem is that they are both quite the same.

The only differance I do have is that an article name is ending with a -XXXXXX where XXXXXX is a number.

How can I do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include some way to differentiate these routes. Here is one approach

```
.state('app.article', {
     url: '/:catName/article/:articleName',
     views: {
         'menuContent': {
             templateUrl: 'templates/article.html',
             controller: 'ArticleCtrl'
         }
     }
 })

 .state('app.category', {
     url: '/:catName/category/:subcatName',
     views: {
         'menuContent': {
             templateUrl: 'templates/category.html',
             controller: 'CategoryCtrl'
         }
     }
 })
```

Comment: That is not an option as the urls are coming from an external source. This is their structure and it can't be changed.
Is there a way to check if the url ends with a number?

Comment: You can try something like [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs). Alternatively, you can use the same controller for both routes and perform different logic based on the param data